# Tableviewcell at element 0 is removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to get the index path.row of a label. The below code works to a point however when I go forward to the next view controller then back, the first tableviewcell disappears. I can click on it and it takes me to the correct next view controller. But it is just not visible.

This is only a problem when I enter the lines where I try and get the label in my prepare for segue.

Does anyone have any ideas why it is disappearing? / Does anyone know how I could access the label of a tableview cell without the first tableview cell disappearing?

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"favouritesPlaceDisplaySegue"]){
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender;
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.favouritesTableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    FavouritesPlaceDisplayViewController *FavPlaceDisplayVC = (FavouritesPlaceDisplayViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
    DealListModel *tempDealListObject = [self.favPlacesObjectArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    FavPlaceDisplayVC.favouritesDisplaytModelObject = tempDealListObject;

    //CODE THAT INTRODUCES ERROR
    UILabel *tempDealNewlabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    tempDealNewlabel.hidden = YES;

    }
}//end of prepare for segue
```

Comment: You seem to hide the label so why should it be visible ? does your cell contains only this label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UILabel *tempDealNewlabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
```

your labels have a constant tag, but you are trying to get it using the row of the tapped cell. are you assigning some tag in cellForRowAtIndexPath for the labels to be able to get them later?

in other words, there is no guarantee that viewWithTag:indexPath.row returns a label

edit:
the default tag for a view is 0, so there is no guarantee that you will get a label for viewWithTag:0 when you tap on your first cell. try assigning some constant number for label's tag like 100

```
static const NSUInteger kLabelTag = 100;
cell.favouritesNewDealLabel.tag = kLabelTag;
```

Comment: In my cellForRowAtIndexPath I have the line:     cell.favouritesNewDealLabel.tag = indexPath.row;

Comment: Let me explain. I am trying to find out if a new deal is available. When a user clicks on the tableview cell they are segued to the deal. When they come back the new deal label should be gone. So what you have I believe would give the new deals label the same value for all. I need to find out which tableview cell has been clicked so I can hide it.

Comment: okay. what i am saying, do not set the label's tag property to 0 (which is what you do for your first row). try setting it to indexPath.row + 100. and in prepareForSegue get it this way `[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row + 100]`

Comment: great! but please try using a constant as i suggested first. it's a proper way to deal with this things.